# JMS Bridge between Active MQ and WebLogic

Tags: java

I am working on a migration project where we have implemented JMS server from WebLogic to Active MQ. THe problem is that the client is still on weblogic and we dont wish to change that .

The connection factory used in server is or.apache.context.InitialContextFactory whereas in weblogic its org.weblogic.WLConnectionFactory. Please help in creating a bridge between these two.

Can't we create a JNDI factory by "org.weblogic....." in active MQ and use it for look up.

Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no, because if you create org.weblogic..... in JNDI, it will look for the same class in activeMQ jar, and will fail. Better to have weblogic on both client and server.